# ¿Como convertir de C# un campo de DateTimePicker a un formato yyyy/MM/dd para que al momento de guardarlo en XML sea la fecha con ese formato?

Tags: c#, xml

Buenas tengo una duda acerca de como poner una variable fecha en formato corto, ya intente el ToShortDateString() ,sin embargo , al abrir el XML se muestra 2022-10-24T00:00:00, no debería aparecer T00:00:00 como podría formatearlo en C# para que en XML se muestre solo la fecha asignada?

```
private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 10);
            //Obtener valores del formulario
            Empleado objE = new Empleado()
            {
                
            //declaramos variables del objeto osea capturamos de las cajas de texto
                ide_emp = int.Parse(lblCodigo.Text),
                nom_emp = txtNombres.Text,
                sue_emp = double.Parse(txtSueldo.Text),
                //fin_emp = dtFecha.Value
                //fin_emp = DateTime.Parse(dtFecha.Value.ToShortDateString())
                //fin_emp = DateTime.Parse(dtFecha.Value.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))
                fin_emp=DateTime.Parse(dtFecha.Value.ToShortDateString().ToString())
            };
            //Enviar un empleado al arreglo,arreglo estructurado para luego crear XML
            arrEmpleados.listadoEmp.Add(objE);
            //Imprimir
            ListadoEmpleados();
            //Para que el correlativo sume
            generarCodigo();

        }
```

Al momento de Deserializar me tira error debido a que el XML me retorna en formato 2022-10-24T00:00:00 y el GUI solo acepta 2022-10-24

```
private void btnAbrirXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
            op.Filter = "Archivo XML|*.xml";
            if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (FileStream fs =new FileStream(op.FileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Empleado));               
                    Empleado objE = (Empleado)xml.Deserialize(fs);
                    
                   
                    lblCodigo.Text = objE.ide_emp.ToString();
                    txtNombres.Text = objE.nom_emp;
                    txtSueldo.Text = objE.sue_emp.ToString();
                    //falta probar
                    dtFecha.Value= DateTime.Parse(objE.fin_emp.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Muy buena noche. Puede que lo único que necesitas es hacer lo siguiente.

```
var tiempo = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("d");
```

Ten en cuenta que el

> Datetime.UtcNow

sería la variable donde tienes tu fecha. Yo la use para tomar la fecha del sistema.

Ahora el ToString ya te trae formatos dependiendo la letra, puedes colocar esa linea en tu codigo y borrar la de, le das **Ctrl+Space** y veras que te da las opciones y puedes ir viendo el formato de estas en sus tooltip.

Si no estas trabajando en Visual Studio pues puede ver lo siguiente: [DateTime.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @Szukający Te funciono?